# How to find best matching for all columns of a 2D array?

Tags: c++, arrays, tree, matching, similarity

Let's say that I have a 2D array that looks like:

```
________________
|10|15|14|20|30|
|14|10|73|71|55|
|73|30|42|84|74|
|14|74|XX|15|10|
----------------
```

As I showed, the columns don't need to be same size.

Now I need to find the best matching for each column (the one that has most exactly the same items and lowest different). Of course, I could do that in n^2 but it's too slow for me. How can I do it?

I thought about a k-dimension tree and finding the closest neighbor for every one, but I don't know if it's good and it will work as I want (probably not).

Result for example:

- First column is most likely third (only three different - 10, 14, 42)
- Second column -> fifth (only two different - 15 and 55)

and so on and so on... :)

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Your example says that column 1 is the most alike- why?  Also, there is no 42 in column 1, and no 55 in column 2.

Comment: Column one has items: 10, 14, 73, 14
Column three has: 14, 73, 42

Now I dont seek for most matching elements, i seek for least not-matching elements. In this case we have 14 in both (so "delete" in mind them for later comparing), 73 in both (so again "delete") and we have left only 3 items that are only on 1 side. If we compare 1st column with others we find that there is more items left between them :)

Also i thking it can be done with a multi dimensional tree and comparing theirs distance (with some work of course) but i'm not "in trees" so much :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know that all the numbers in the table are 2-digit numbers  (i.e. 10 =< x <100), for each column create an array of booleans where you will mark the existing numbers:

```
bool array[5][100];
std::fill( &array[0][0], &array[0][0] + sizeof(array) , false ); // init to false
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j <5; j++)
  {
     array[i][table[i][j]] = true;
  }
}
```

Should be easy from there.